How to indent after each <br/> but not on the first line?
I have <div> elements that may contain one or several <br/>, i.e., hard line breaks. I would like the text of the new line after each <br/> to be indented, but the first line of the <div> should not be indented.
I first tried div { text-indent: 2rem each-line; }. This indents the text after each <br/>, but it also indents the first line of the <div>. So I tried to remove the indentation of the first line with div:first-line { text-indent: 0rem; }, but this does not work, apparently because text-indent is not an allowed property on the :first-line pseudo-element. Neither can I use a negative margin or padding on the :first-line pseudo-element, it seems. Is there a way to achieve what I want to achieve?


<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam placerat metus turpis, et auctor eros porttitor sed.
  <br/>Sed ornare eget metus in interdum. Nulla ut orci eget eros ullamcorper semper.
  <br/>Aliquam fringilla urna lectus, ac vestibulum diam sodales eget.
</div>



So, in this example, "Sed ornare" and "Aliquam fringilla" should be indented, but not "Lorem ipsum". Here is the CSS I tried:
div { text-indent: 2rem each-line; }
div:first-line { text-indent: 0rem; }

Here is a picture of what I am trying to achieve:


You could add spaces manually at  the beginning of the sentences you want to indent using &nbsp.

@MrIzzat hardcoding spaces with `&nbsp) is the worst thing you can do and an absolute mess. Besides that, it is prone to errors.

For a simple thing like indentation hardcoding spaces would be like adding a tab to the text, like most people would when writing an essay when starting a new paragaph. Using CSS is overboard for simple indentation.

CSS is never overboard. Besides that. Just imagine writing a 30-page essay with 100 lines each. Then having to manually indent every single 3k liens with spaces... That's why you use CSS and never hardcode such a thing. Besides it can be a mess with screen readers.

It depends on the use case. If indentation is needed for only two lines, it's much cleaner and easier to use &nbsp. But if indentation is needed for a lot lines, as you mentioned, CSS would be the better option.

Not with CSS since it cannot detect text nodes. Use proper paragraphs instead of br and it is a simple proposition.

@Paulie_D: I cannot change the HTML code, I need to use CSS. I see that my question was closed, but I do not think that my question is a duplicate of the other question. There might be a solution to my particular problem that would not work for the related question. For example, maybe there is a style that can be applied to div:first-line that achieves the desired effect (although I have not found such a style, which is why I am asking the question).

There are limited style options for first-line and indenting is not included - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line

A hacky idea using negative margin but only available on Firefox due to the support of each-line


.indent {
  text-indent: 2rem each-line;
}
.indent:before {
  content:"";
  margin-right: -2rem;
}

/* fallback to avoid the overflow */
@supports not (text-indent: 2rem each-line) {
  .indent {
    text-indent: 2rem;
  }
}
<div class="indent">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam placerat metus turpis, et auctor eros porttitor sed.
  <br>Sed ornare eget metus in interdum. Nulla ut orci eget eros ullamcorper semper.
  <br>Aliquam fringilla urna lectus, ac vestibulum diam sodales eget.
</div>




Well, this is something you cannot do reliably with your current HTML structure. I tried to retain your document structure (<div> text <br> more text <br> etc. </div>), but nothing works well, as the <br> element only seems to respond under certain conditions, like setting display: none to remove the line breaks or margin.
Furthermore, the MDN doc about the Line Break element itself also notes that there is little to do to style it:

As such, it has no dimensions or visual output of its own, and there is very little you can do to style it.

What you could do instead, is wrapping the paragraphs in <p> tags, like this:
<div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam placerat metus turpis, et auctor eros porttitor sed.
    </p>
    <p>
        Sed ornare eget metus in interdum. Nulla ut orci eget eros ullamcorper semper.
    </p>
    <p>
        Aliquam fringilla urna lectus, ac vestibulum diam sodales eget.
    </p>
</div>

And then apply a style to p:
div p {
    text-indent: 2rem each-line;
}

div p:first-child {
    text-indent: 0;
}


fundamental issue is that CSS can't target text nodes that come after a  tag without some kind of containing element around that text.( I tried several approches with /br but nothing seems to work)
so i have two working solutions

Solution 1 : (html-css)



div p {
  margin: 0;  
}

div p:not(:first-child) {
  text-indent: 2rem;
}
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam placerat metus turpis, et auctor eros porttitor sed.</p>
  <p>Sed ornare eget metus in interdum. Nulla ut orci eget eros ullamcorper semper.</p>
  <p>Aliquam fringilla urna lectus, ac vestibulum diam sodales eget.</p>
</div>




Solution 2 : (html-css-js)



function wrapTextAfterBr(element) {
  let html = element.innerHTML;
  
  let parts = html.split(/<br\s*\/?>/i);
  
  let newHtml = parts.map((part, index) => {
    if (index === 0) return part;
    return `<span>${part}</span>`;
  }).join('<br>');
  
  element.innerHTML = newHtml;
}
document.querySelectorAll('.indent-after-br').forEach(wrapTextAfterBr);
.indent-after-br br + * {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

.indent-after-br {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.indent-after-br > *:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 2rem;
}
<div class="indent-after-br">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  
  <br/>Sed ornare eget metus...
  <br/>Aliquam fringilla urna...
</div>



